# Pagination in spring boot looping the association data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi i am trying to implement pagination in spring boot. i have 3 tables.

1) Post -> Which store the post like small tweets.

2) Profile -> User details

3) Authentication -> User's Authentication table.

The Relationship between these 3 tables are as follows.

```
 profile have OneToOne relation with Authentication.  
 profile have OneToMany relation with Post.

 authentication have OneToOne with Profile.

 Post have OneToOne with Profile.
```

When i am trying the Pagination as follows for the post table

**Post.java**

```
 @Entity
 public class Post {

     @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
     private Profile profile;

     @Override
     public String toString() {
          return "Post [id=" + id + ", tweet=" + tweet + ", profile=" + profile + "]";
}
```

**PostRepository.Java**

```
 @Repository
  public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post,Integer> {
      Post findById(int id);
  }
```

**PersonPagingService .Java**

```
 public interface PersonPagingService {

Page<Post> getAllPosts(Pageable pageable);

}
```

**PostService.Java**

```
@Service
public class PostService implements PersonPagingService {

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<Post> getAllPosts(Pageable pageable){
        return postRepository.findAll(pageable);
    }
}
```

**PostController.Java**'

```
@RestController
public class PostController{

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public List<Post> checkThesSignupEmailIsNew(Pageable pageable) {
       Page<Post> posts = PersonPagingService.getAllPosts(pageable);
       return posts.getContent();
    }
}
```

When i am sending the request for

[image]

Raw Data

[image: RAW DATA of response]

***If i am deleting the Relationship in POST.JAVA then it's working fine.***

Please help me to understand what mistake i am doing.

**don't worry about authentication data it's test data **

**Profile.Java**

```
@Entity
 public class Profile {

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile")
  List<Post> posts; 

   @Override
   public String toString() {
    return "Profile [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", email=" + email + ", location=" + location + "]";
   }
}
```

It Fetching one Post From the database

```
[![one Post][3]][3]
```

[image]

Comment: This has nothing to do with pagination nor Spring Data. It is a result of how you mapped your entities. there is bi-directional relationship and as you haven't excluded one side to be exported to JSON it will loop forever.

Comment: @M.Deinum. If that's the case when i am fetching the data without pagingandsortting repository if i use JPArepository interface that time it worked fine. it fetched whole post data with out looping. Why it worked that time

Comment: I highly doubt it did and you had different changes as well. Fact is you have circulair references you should exclude the list of posts from the profile when sending JSON (or vice versa).

Comment: @M.Deinum. it fetching one Post correctly from database. please find the screenshot of POST/11 view page no looping

Comment: Trust me that that is the issue. Put `@JsonIgnore` on the collection in the `Profile`. It is a well known issue with bi-directional relationships. Also the single post isn't JSON that is merely the `toString` representation of your objects, which doesn't contain the loop.

Comment: @M.Deinum it resolved the issue. but i need this relation means post as well as the author profile detail how to make it successful like how it displaying in a single post

Comment: As stated you are comparing apples and oranges( the looping is a JSON result, the single one the `toString` representation). Where do I say you need to exclude both? You still have the post and the profile so everything is there...

Comment: @M.Deinum in FindAll() i am not getting the profile details only post details are fetched.

Comment: The `Post` has a relation to `Profile` (do you understand how JPA works?) hence everything is there. You only want to prevent Jackson from serializing the bi-directional relation ship, hence you need to add `@JsonIgnore` to the `posts` mapping in `Profile`.

Comment: M.Deinum Thank you so much. i was confused. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Returning `Entities` from your `Controllers` is not a good idea. Because `JSON` serializers like `Jackson` will try to serialize your entity to `JSON` with all of it's properties. And since your objects are `Hibernate` proxies, it may lead to some issues.

You may fetch too many records from database that you don't need.

You may face with `LazyInitiailzatinException` if `Hibernate` tries to fetch lazy properties that hasn't been fetched but the `Session` is closed.

In the case of bidirectional relationships, you will face infinite loop trap.

Instead, it's better to have `Model` Or `DTO` classes for your `Entities` and convert your `Entity` objects to `Model` or `DTO` objects and set the properties you want to be in the response in those objects and return them.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a loop when creating JSON. I had the same problem, until I annotate one part of the relation with `@JsonIgnore` (same for equals and hashcode (Lombok)).

Comment: hi Sven it will ignore the Profile details in the post page but i need the post as well as the Profile details for that post. how to fetch that if i ignore it there .

Comment: Ok, first just a short question. How can profile-post having a OneToMany while post-profile has a OneToOne relation?

Comment: Well if you need the post and the profile, you could as hassan said construct a Model. As Hassan said, it's better than returning the whole entity. For security reasons it's better too, just return properties, which user's allowed to view.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent infinite loop just remove a `get` method of related Entity that you have used in your entity class. Eg:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "profile")
  List<Post> posts;
```

I assume that you might have made getter and setter method of `posts` so only adding 'setter' method might solve your problem.